# How to use Arithmetic in the CQL statement

Tags: cassandra, cql

you know, we can perform calculations in SQL statement by use arithmetic expression. An arithmetic expression can contain column names, numeric numbers, and arithmetic operations. Below is the SQL statement Syntax:

> SELECT [arithmetic operator]...
>    FROM [table_name] 
>    WHERE [expression];

and now, I want to do the same thing in the CQL statement. what is the Syntax of CQL statement?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: FYI - Cassandra now allows Arithmetic operators in CQL: https://medium.com/building-the-open-data-stack/arithmetic-operators-in-apache-cassandra-4-0-c5a3185d683

Answer (score 2):

Arithmetic is not supported in CQL. You may be able to do some similar things using [UDFS](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/functions.html#functions)

See the full standard here
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic operations are currently not supported by Cassandra.

But nothing is lost: there's a [Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11935) that specifically addresses your issue. The only problem is that this is going to be released with Cassandra 4.0...